# Angular HttpClient not interacting with Spring Controller

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I have encountered an issue where my Angular application's HttpClient doesn't seem to be interacting correctly with my Spring Controller. I have configured the necessary endpoints and methods in the Spring Controller. The Angular service isn't making the corresponding HTTP requests using HttpClient.

I have verified the correctness of the API URLs, ensured that the CORS configuration is properly set up, and checked for any error messages in the browser's developer console. Developer console shows no call to endpoint. All checks was made in incognito mode, cache issues are excluded.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps that can help me diagnose and resolve this issue effectively.

Controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('" + Role.MANAGER_ROLE_NAME + "') or hasRole('" + Role.STORE_ROLE_NAME + "')")
@GetMapping(value = "{organizationId}")
public List<SapAsset> getAssets(@PathVariable final long organizationId) {
    return sapAssetService.getStoreAssets(organizationId);
}
```

Angular:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SecureHttpClientService} from '../../core/services/secure-http-client.service';
import {Asset} from "../models/asset";
import {DateTimeFormatterService} from "../../core/services/date-time-formatter.service";
import {AlertService} from "../../core/services/alert.service";

@Injectable()
export class AssetService {

    protected url = '/assets';
    private readonly storeAssetsCacheKey = 'cachedStoreAssets';
    private readonly dcAssetsCacheKey = 'cachedDcAssets';

    constructor(private secureHttpClient: SecureHttpClientService, private dateTimeFormatterService: DateTimeFormatterService,
                private alertService: AlertService) {
    }

    public getAssets(storeId: number): Promise<Asset[]> {
        const cachedStoreAssets = this.getFromCache(this.storeAssetsCacheKey);
        if (Array.isArray(cachedStoreAssets)) {
            return Promise.resolve(cachedStoreAssets);
        }

        return this.secureHttpClient.get(this.url + '/' + storeId)
            .then((response: Asset[]) => {
                this.saveToCache(response, this.storeAssetsCacheKey);
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                this.alertService.error("general.sap_error");
            });
    }
```

Angular rest wrapper:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientService} from './http-client.service';
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthService} from '../../authentication/services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class SecureHttpClientService {

    apiUrl: string;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClientService, private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    private createAuthHeader() {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken(),
        });

        const options = {
            headers
        };

        return options;
    }

    public get(url: string): any {
        return this.httpClient.get(url, this.createAuthHeader());
    }
```

Angular get service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {EnvironmentSpecificService} from './environment-specific.service';
import {EnvSpecific} from '../models/env-specific';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {PageLoadingService} from '../../../services/page-loading.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {

    apiUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private environmentSpecificService: EnvironmentSpecificService, private pageLoadingService: PageLoadingService) {
        environmentSpecificService.subscribe(this, this.setApiUrl);
    }

    private setApiUrl(caller: any, es: EnvSpecific) {
        const thisCaller = caller as HttpClientService;
        caller.apiUrl = es.apiUrl;
    }

    public getApiUrl(url: string): string {
        return this.apiUrl + url;
    }

    private extractBase64ImageData(response: Response): String {
        return 'data:image/png;base64,' + response.text();
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error || '';
            const err = JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(error);
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }

    public get(url: string, options?: any): any {
        const promise = this.http.get(this.getApiUrl(url), options).toPromise();
        this.pageLoadingService.addPromise(promise);
        return promise.catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Place where it called from:

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AlertService} from "../../../../core/services/alert.service";
import {DateTimeFormatterService} from "../../../../core/services/date-time-formatter.service";
import {NotificationService} from "../../../../core/services/notification.service";
import {Asset} from "../../../models/asset";
import {Organization} from "../../../../organizations/models/organization";
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {AuthService} from "../../../../authentication/services/auth.service";
import {OrganizationService} from "../../../../organizations/services/organization.service";
import {MatSelectChange} from "@angular/material/select";
import {Utils} from "../../../../core/utils/utils";
import {AssetService} from "../../../services/asset.service";
import {RoleEnum} from "../../../../authentication/enums/role-enum";
import {ExternalMovementsService} from "../../../services/external-movements.service";
import {FormUtils} from "../../../../shared/utils/form-utils";

@Component({
    selector: 'create-external-order',
    templateUrl: './create-external-movement-order.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-external-movement-order.component.css']
})
export class CreateExternalMovementOrderComponent implements OnInit {

    filterValue: string = "";
    assignableOrganizations: Organization[] = [];
    filteredOrganizations: Organization[];
    assignableAssets: Asset[] = [];
    filteredAssets: Asset[] = [];

    public storeFilterControl = new FormControl();

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private dateTimeFormatterService: DateTimeFormatterService, private zone: NgZone,
                private alertService: AlertService, private router: Router,
                private notificationService: NotificationService,
                private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private externalMovementsService: ExternalMovementsService,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private organizationService: OrganizationService,
                private assetService: AssetService) {

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            fromOrganizationId: [null, Validators.compose([])],
            toOrganization: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if ((this.authService.getRole() == RoleEnum.MANAGER)) {
            this.organizationService.getAssignableWithDc().then(result => {
                this.assignableOrganizations = result.filter(item => item.externalId != null);
                this.filteredOrganizations = this.assignableOrganizations;

                const sourceOrganization = this.externalMovementsService.getOrderSourceOrganization();
                if (!sourceOrganization) {
                    this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required]));
                    this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').updateValueAndValidity();
                } else {
                    this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').setValue(sourceOrganization.id);
                    this.loadAssets(sourceOrganization.id);
                }

                const destinationOrganization = this.externalMovementsService.getOrderDestinationOrganization();
                this.form.get("toOrganization").setValue(destinationOrganization);
            }, error => {
                this.alertService.genericError();
            });
        } else {
            const storeId = this.authService.getOrganizationId();
            this.assignableOrganizations = [this.authService.getOrganization()];
            this.filteredOrganizations = [this.authService.getOrganization()];
            this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').setValue(storeId);
            this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').disable();

            this.loadAssetsAndSelectOrganization(storeId);
        }
    }

    navigateToCheckout() {
        FormUtils.validateAllFormFields(this.form);

        if (this.form.valid) {
            this.externalMovementsService.setOrderDestinationOrganization(this.form.get("toOrganization").value);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/movements/external/create/checkout');
        }
    }

    loadAssets(storeId: number) {
        this.assetService.getAssets(storeId).then(result => {
            this.assignableAssets = result;
            this.filteredAssets = result;
        }, error => {
            this.alertService.genericError();
        });
    }

    fromOrganizationSelected(event: MatSelectChange) {
        const storeId = event.value;
        this.updateSelectedOrganization(storeId);
    }

    updateSelectedOrganization(organizationId: number) {
        const previousOrganizationId = this.externalMovementsService.getOrderSourceOrganization()?.id || null;
        const orderHasItems = this.externalMovementsService.getOrderItems().length > 0;

        if (previousOrganizationId !== null && previousOrganizationId !== organizationId) {
            if (orderHasItems) {
                this.alertService.confirm(() => {
                    this.externalMovementsService.clearOrder();
                    this.loadAssetsAndSelectOrganization(organizationId);
                }, "You are about to change order organization, all cart items will be lost, proceed?", null, () => {
                    this.form.get('fromOrganizationId').setValue(previousOrganizationId);
                });
            } else {
                this.loadAssetsAndSelectOrganization(organizationId);
            }
        } else {
            this.loadAssetsAndSelectOrganization(organizationId);
        }
    }

    private loadAssetsAndSelectOrganization(organizationId: number) {
        this.assignableAssets = [];
        this.loadAssets(organizationId);
        const organization = this.assignableOrganizations.filter(item => item.id == organizationId).pop();
        this.externalMovementsService.setOrderSourceOrganization(organization);
    }

    isItemAlreadyAddedToCart(asset: Asset) {
        return this.externalMovementsService.isItemAlreadyAddedToCart(asset.assetId);
    }

    addToOrder(asset: Asset) {
        this.externalMovementsService.addToOrder(asset);
    }

    filterUpdated(filterValue) {
        if (filterValue == null || filterValue == "") {
            this.filteredAssets = this.assignableAssets;
        } else {
            this.filteredAssets = this.assignableAssets.filter(element => {
                for (let value of Object.values(element)) {
                    if (value) {
                        if (value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    }

    removeFromOrder(asset: Asset) {
        this.externalMovementsService.deleteFromOrder(asset.assetId);
    }

    clearOrder() {
        this.externalMovementsService.clearOrder();
    }

    shoppingCartIsNotEmpty() {
        return this.externalMovementsService.getOrderItems().length != 0;
    }

    navigateBack() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/movements/external');
    }

    formatOrganizationTitle(organization: Organization): string {
        if (!Utils.isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(organization.externalId)) {
            return organization.name + " (" + organization.externalId + ")";
        }

        return organization.name;
    }


    getFormattedDate(date: number): string {
        return this.dateTimeFormatterService.formatTimestampToDisplayDate(date);
    }

    updateFilteredOrganizations() {
        const value = this.storeFilterControl.value;
        if (!value) {
            this.filteredOrganizations = this.assignableOrganizations;
        } else {
            this.filteredOrganizations = this.assignableOrganizations
                .filter(item => {
                    const searchIn = item.name + ' ' + item.externalId;
                    return searchIn.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
                });
        }
    }

    onPanelClose() {
        this.storeFilterControl.setValue('');
        this.updateFilteredOrganizations();
    }

    getAssetTooltip(asset: Asset) {
        return this.assetService.getAssetTooltip(asset);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share code along with classes and imports.

Comment: Added all necessary information

Comment: From where are you calling the assetService.getAssets()?

Comment: It's working fine. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ujegec?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Do I need caching expiration mechanism to work? Added place where it called from

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to subscribe() to your observable. The Angular HttpClient's get() method returns an observable, not a Promise.

Just add .subscribe() after the closing parentheses and you should be good.

Comment: This part of code returns Promis:
const promise = this.http.get(this.getApiUrl(url), options).toPromise();